# Message Box Pops up Repeatedly in a Timer

Tags: c#, messagebox

I am creating the famous game Tic Tac Toe.

I am facing a problem with a message box repeatedly appearing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = turn;
        if (turn=="x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn=="0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button4.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button4.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button5.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button5.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button6.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button7.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button7.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button8.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button8.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button9.Text = turn;
        if (turn == "x")
        {
            turn = "0";
        }
        else if (turn == "0")
        {
            turn = "x";
        }
        button9.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "x" && button2.Text == "x" && button3.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
      else if (button4.Text == "x" && button5.Text == "x" && button6.Text == "x")
        {
           MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
       else if (button7.Text == "x" && button8.Text == "x" && button9.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");


        }
       else if (button1.Text == "x" && button5.Text == "x" && button9.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");


        }
       else if (button3.Text == "x" && button5.Text == "x" && button7.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
       else if (button1.Text == "x" && button4.Text == "x" && button7.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
      else if (button2.Text == "x" && button5.Text == "x" && button8.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
       else if (button3.Text == "x" && button6.Text == "x" && button9.Text == "x")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");

        }
      else if (button1.Text == "0" && button2.Text == "0" && button3.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");

        }
       else if (button4.Text == "0" && button5.Text == "0" && button6.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");


        }
       else if (button7.Text == "0" && button8.Text == "0" && button9.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 1 Won");


        }
       else if (button1.Text == "0" && button5.Text == "0" && button9.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "0" && button5.Text == "0" && button7.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "0" && button6.Text == "0" && button9.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");
        }
        else if (button2.Text == "0" && button5.Text == "0" && button8.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");

        }
        else if (button1.Text == "0" && button4.Text == "0" && button7.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User 2 Won");          
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Is the MessageBox displaying more frequently than expected? Not as often as needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't disable the timer, it will continue to tick, and if that happens to be while another messagebox is still shown, it will show another one

You can disable your timer in the tick method, and wait for the response to enable it again, like so

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
MessageBox.Show();
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: @RohailAhmed You are welcome, in general, you up/downvote the answers that you see fit, and if you get an answer that helped your solution you can mark it as an answer (there should be a grayed out checkmark next to the response). If you click it, you confirm that this was a correct answer for your question, which then helps future users who might have the same problem as you had (and we both gain a bit of rep). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) you can find more info about it (I only share it as you are apparently new to this site)